# Arduino 'Hello World' not printing properly

Tags: arduino

I am doing a sample hello world on arduino uno. here is my sample code.

```
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
}

void loop()
{
  Serial.println('Hello world');
}
```

This is giving me weird output on the serial monitor (with 9600 BR). I get a continuous output of the following:

```
27748
27748
27748
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try changing: `Serial.println('Hello world');` to `Serial.println("Hello world");`
I haven't played around with my Arduino in a few months, but I think you need double quotes and not single quotes for strings.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know in others but in arduino uno, `Serial.println` doesn't work with strings, you need to use `Serial.write`

https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Write